# I can rest ngForm to default values, but cannot set initial values (angular2+)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using Angular2+, and I have a simple ngForm, that has a reset button, and a reset to defaults button at the bottom.

[View Plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-58qtwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I want to be able to see the default values that appear when I hit the "reset form with default values" button, when the page is loaded/initialized.

I have tried doing:

```
<input type="text" name="" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" 
title="" name="name" [(ngModel)]="defaultValues.name" required>
```

Where I can set an initial value, but this component will not reset...

VS

```
<input type="text" name="" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" 
title="" name="name" ngModel required>
```

Where I can reset this component, but not see the initial value in the text field..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the ngModel value:

```
[(ngModel)]="values.name"
[(ngModel)]="values.amount"
```

For setting the defaultValues you can override the property with something like this:

```
values: any;
defaultValues = {
    amount: 20,
    name: 'defaultName'
} 

constructor() {
    this.values = this.cloneDefaultValues(this.defaultValues);
}

private cloneDefaultValues(param: any) {
    //  JSON parse and stringify methods because js use references on complex objects
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(param));
}

resetFormWithDefaultValues(){
   this.values = this.cloneDefaultValues(this.defaultValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Edited with the return

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand One way Binding Vs Two way data binding.
Once you have used [(ngModel)] it is possible to both assign values and get values easily.

I have updated your slack

```
[(ngModel)]="model.name"
[(ngModel)]="model.amount"
```

once i updated this working now.

Here your slackbitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpigb7

here is more reference for understanding,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-one-and-two-way-data-bindings-with-examples/

https://medium.com/@milosbejda/one-way-and-two-way-bindings-in-angular-4-explained-b5ec280767ec

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. Try changing either of the values using the form controls and then reset the form with default values.

Comment: This shows the default values when you first see the form, but now it will not reset to default values